# Parent and child event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, inspinia

I am creating a web page that uses bootstrap, jquery and inspinia template.

I use 3 files namely
index.html - Where I import all my scripts

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div ng-include="'/app/components/navigation/navigation.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'/app/components/header and footer/headerFooter.html'"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/inspinia.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

navigation.html - Where my side bar is in place
headerFooter.html - Where the button for sidebar toggle is place

inspinia.js - where the event listener is place

```
$('.navbar-minimalize').on("click", function (event) {
    $("body").toggleClass("mini-navbar");
    SmoothlyMenu();

});
```

The question is, Why does whenever I press the button the side-bar doesn't turn into mini-navbar (class not applying) is this kind of setup.

but if all the div element is in index and not using `ng-include` the button is toggling properly.

BTW: I am using bootstrap 3.xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

`$('.navbar-minimalize').on('click, function() {});`

to:

`$('body').on('click', '.navbar-minimalize', function() {});`

Angular insert your HTML at runtime, so your jQuery code doesn't know about your DOM on start.

Comment: Yes it works! Can you explain further, is my angularjs and jquery contradicting to each other?

Comment: In simple words - your jQuery runs before Angular, so `$('.navbar-minimalize')` don't return any element.

Comment: My code works, because it uses event delegation, read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: The most important part: „Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on().”

Comment: I get it now, I tried interchanging the script call of angular and jquery, it also works. Therefore I don't need to change anything from the Inspinia template. Thank you so much.